# Apache Kafka 0.8.2 Topic Creation Error

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using the following command to start the broker and create the topic:

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties & bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic read-singnals
```

Prior to doing this, I start zoo keeper:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeer.properties
```

When I tried to list all the topics that are available, using the following command:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

I get nothing printed! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the steps (similar to the ones mentioned) and also mentioned in the [documentation link](http://kafka.apache.org/082/documentation.html#quickstart).
I tried out the steps on a vagrant CentoS minimal instance (relativkreativ/centos-7-minimal) and I received the expected output.
I even tried the same name for the topic (just to make sure if it wasn't the hyphen in the name causing the issue) and it worked as expected.

Followed the steps below on vagrant centos instance

```
sudo yum install java
wget http://a.mbbsindia.com/kafka/0.8.2.0/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0.tgz
tar -xzf kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0.tgz
cd kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties &
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties &

bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic testme
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic testme2
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic testme2-test1
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic read-singnals
```

Expected results below

```
[vagrant@localhost kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0]$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
read-singnals
testme
testme2
testme2-test1
```

Please do let me know if you are able to find any other version differences or if you are able to solve the issue